# Dropdownlist onselectedindexchanged not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a datagrid that has dropdowns in one column :

```
            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResultId" Visible="false" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CurrentId", "{0:g}") %>'/>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrentValue" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCurrentValue_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

I set the selected value for each dropdown based on a value taken from the database on ItemDataBound.

Now if the user changes the value of one of the dropdowns, i would like to save the value from that dropdown.

My id is that i have the database-id in lblResultId and use that to save the selectedvalue from the dropdown to the database via a linq query. However, i am already stuck on the 'onselectedindexchanged' for the dropdownlists not firing.....
Any suggestions how to procede or how to do this differently ?

Comment: Does Grid View Placed inside Update Panel ?. For better solution show your dropdown select change event also.

Comment: fyi `<asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>` no need to put like this as `<asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>` this only works. If you have text and value different then you can differentiate with text and value.